# FormatException: Invalid UTF-8 byte (at offset 6)

Tags: flutter, dart

Why do I get an error with this single line of code?

```
    final pdfString = " (T) 20.5 (–H) 4 (E) ]     % 5-element array of strings, reals, and intege";
    print(utf8.decode(pdfString.codeUnits));
```

why I get

> FormatException: Invalid UTF-8 byte (at offset 11)

I copied this string from O'Reilly book.

And independently of the context, how to recover the `pdfString` if I have its byte representation only ?

Comment: Without the PDF context, how to recover that string from its byte representation ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the documentation for [String.codeUnits](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/String/codeUnits.html):

> An unmodifiable list of the **UTF-16 code units** of this string.

(Emphasis added.)

In effect, you are calling `utf8.decode()` on a UTF-16 string, which is not going to work.

If you provide more context about what you're actually trying to do, I may be able to offer a suggestion.

Comment: you're right my friend.  I changed    final pdfBytes = pdfString.codeUnits;  to 
    final pdfBytes =  utf8.encode(pdfString);  and it works! It would have helped if you added that in your answer